# In Chrome DevTools, prevent debugger from pausing inside certain files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Running ahead, the "Blackboxing" feature of DevTools does not help.

So, I have a javascript app, and I want to press "pause script execution" button (see image), and then wait until debugger stops on first line executed.

[image]

I need to know which code starts executing after some UI operation.

The problem is in one file of the project where there is a `setInterval` running all the time. Is there a way to ignore that file, in other words provide DevTools with a blacklist of files for pausing?

I can dig in code and turn that particular `setInterval` off. But using a DevTools feature (if exists) would make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to kill all `setInterval`s on the page is

```
var maxTimeoutOrIntervalId = setTimeout(()=>{}, 0);

for (var i = 0; i < maxTimeoutOrIntervalId; i++) {
    clearInterval(i);
}
```